# CSS flexible padding-divs with centered text inside, max-padding

Tags: css, responsive-design, centering

[image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m37jwp25nsvav3h/Screenshot%202015-05-29%2014.25.18.png?dl=0)

[codepen](http://codepen.io/branovaclav/pen/WvRprX)

hello, i need help with css styling.
i'm trying to have a responsive main menu,
but cannot figure out a way to keep the text horizontally-centered within the item boxes, once these start to shrink due to low viewport width.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

this allows for flexible horizontally-centered menu items

```
.item {
  padding: 5px 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

what happens is that once the boxes start to shrink, the left padding is preserved while the right one is being "overflow-hidden", which puts the text off-center with respect to their .item containers.
i need the text to stay centered within the item box, while keeping some fixed horizontal padding around the text (enlaring the item box) when width is sufficient.

this is what i tried, but unsurprisingly it didn't work :-)

```
.item {
  width: calc(auto + 60px);
  text-align: center;
}
```

thanks for help

Comment: any jsfiddle or demo?

Comment: use media query for low viewport friend.

Comment: i use media queries for low viewport. that would be the mobile view.
this is the desktop view. however since i cannot guarantee the amount and width of individual menu items, i need the view to shrink/degrade usably and aesthetically (that's what flexbox is designed for anyway). your advice would indicate i would need to create a media query for every possible viewport width :-)

Comment: i have added a codepen example. try to resize viewport window to see how the text labels get off-center

Answer (score 0):

What about using line-height?

Like this http://jsbin.com/capixobihe/1/

```
#menu ul li {
  padding:6px;
  margin:0 5px;
  font-family:Arial;
  line-height:30px; /* <--- Set this */
  background-color:#FFF;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: the issue is with horizontal centering, not vertical. i need the text to be horizontally centered within a container, that is (text-width + left & right padding) px wide or smaller.